# Why Does My Generic Method Require a Cast?

Tags: java

I have a service layer method that I want to expose that should return an instance of an object that extends CMSContent (e.g. Delivery Time, Price).  However, in method **getCMSContent**, the compiler is insisting that I do a cast to **T**.  Is this cast below acceptable, or am I defeating the purpose of generics?

I compile with "-Xlint:unchecked" and receive no warnings, and it functions as I expect.

```
    public <T extends CMSContent> T getCMSContent(String cmsKey, Class<T> clazz) {
        T cmsInstance = (T) CMSObjectCache.getCachedCMSObject(cmsKey, clazz);
        return cmsInstance;
    }
```

This is the entire method of getCachedCMSObject

```
public static <T> T getCachedCMSObject(String objectKey, Class<T> cls) {
    init();
    CMSObject cmsObject = cmsObjectCache.get(objectKey);
    if (cmsObject != null) {
        return cmsObject.getCMSObject(cls);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What's the signature / implementation of  `getCachedCMSObject()`?

Comment: Also, according to your sample, *either* the cast should be unnecessary, *or* you should be getting an unchecked warning. And if it's necessary, you should be using `clazz.cast(…)` instead – never do `(T) obj`. (For given values of "never", sometimes your code returns the correct type even if the type checker can't prove it.)

Comment: @millimoose What is the advantage of `clazz.cast()`? I haven't heard this before.

Comment: `clazz.cast` does an actual check, and can throw a `ClassCastException`; `(T)` for a generic `T` does not.  (Unless `T` is known to extend some other class, in which case it only checks that the value is actually an instance of _that_.)

Comment: @xxpor If you have a *type token* like in the above example: `Class<T> clazz`, then `clazz.cast(obj)` is the runtime / reflection equivalent of `(T) clazz.cast(obj)`. Except that, as Louis points out, it actually works. Often, when the compiler warns you about an unchecked cast when using generics, you can (and should) modify your code to replace the unchecked cast with `class.cast()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the the signature of `getCachedCMSObject` is:

```
T getCachedCMSObject(String cmsKey, Class<T> clazz)
```

your cast is to `T` is unnecessary although you may want to throw an exception rather than return a null.

Comment: "Then you need to cast to T, but I would double check to make sure you always get back an object of type T." – in this case, you can use `clazz.cast(…)`, no need to doublecheck.

Comment: @millimoose afaik clazz.cast isn't doing any magic. If the object passed isn't of type clazz then it will fail just as bad as (clazz) would.

Comment: `(T) object` can never throw a `ClassCastException`; `clazz.cast` will.  That's the advantage to using `clazz.cast`: it fails faster.  (Except if you have something like `T extends Comparable<T>`, in which case it'll throw a `ClassCastException` if the value isn't comparable, but...`clazz.cast` does the _full_ check.)

Comment: @JacobRaihle To add to what Louis said: The difference is when using generics. Of course there's no difference between doing say `(List) obj` and `List.class.cast(obj)`, but that's not the case in this question. Casting to a *type parameter* compiles to a cast to the upper bound on the type parameter. More often than not this is `Object`, which means it's a no-op; even if it's not it's probably not the check you expect. This is why the Java compiler warns you against *unchecked* casts if you do this.

Comment: @JacobRaihle It's not *completely* typesafe, mostly because you can't make type tokens of generic classes, but it helps. (E.g. you can't cast to `Comparable<String>` because there is no such thing as `Comparable<String>.class`; and you can't use super type tokens either because it'd require a lot of boilerplate and busywork and still not work for third-party code.)